# How to use webpack.DefinePlugin for simple value replacement

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a simple replacement working as a webpack plugin:

```
// ...
const APIroot = npm_package_config_api;
// ...
```

... and a simple webpack plugin defined in webpack.config.js:

```
{
// ...
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        npm_package_config_api: JSON.stringify('some value')
    })
]
// ...
```

... which is all working perfectly. However, I want to make a small change - so that my unit tests aren't complaining about `ReferenceError: npm_package_config_api is not defined`, which is completely understandable. So, I attempt to make the change to:

```
// ...
const APIroot = 'npm_package_config_api';
// ...
```

... and now the replacement isn't happening at all.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do what I am attempting?

Comment: What kind of unit test are you using (maybe some framework you are using)?

Comment: @Everettss the testing framework I am using is Jest but they don't matter really because they aren't getting the correct code to evaluate.